# CSS z-index issue when inside of table cell

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, z-index

I have a calendar/table that when you hover over each day we have a small popup that is absolutely position below each cell.

To make this work I have added a `<div style="relative" />` inside each cell. Works fine in FF although when you hover over it in IE the z-index is being ignored.

[image]

I have tried all of the hacks I can think of to get it to work in IE 7 + 8.

Comment: don't have ie here right now but did you try display: inline ?

Comment: Since messing with z-index's is getting messy, the best solution would be to put all of the popups outside of and after the table. That will fix your layering issues.

Comment: Give us your code man!  Where Arr ze C0dez!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No need for all the individual `z-indexes` on the `.wrapper` div's inside the `td` elements (they can all be set to `1` I believe), and set these properties:

```
/* add these two to your selector */
#calendar tbody td {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* create this new selector */
#calendar tbody td:hover {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Using firebug and IE's developer tools, it appeared to me that it was working in Firefox and IE7 and 8.

Comment: This half worked although the position relative didn't work on the `td`, so I added a `.wrapper div` inside each cell. Then `td:hover .wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `position: relative` and a `z-index` on the `table` as well as the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your absolutely positioned hover element, place a relative positioned div and give it a z-index of like 500. Ie7 considers absolute and relative positioned elements as having seperate z-index stacks

```
<div class="hoverContent" style="opacity: 1; display: none;">
    <div style='position:relative;z-index:500;'>
        <a class="btn popme" >Book Now</a>
        <p>content etc</p>
        <label></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Something like that i guess

Comment: Nice idea to get around this issue, although this too didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

I have used this to help me with a similar problem before:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-ie-z-index/

If this doesn't help does it matter if you give the table itself a z-index of 1 or something lower?

Comment: I was able to achieve this in smarty although had no effect

Comment: Same sort of answer as @JustinY by incrementing the z-index

Comment: Check the demo now, I have add this in smarty instead of jquery

Comment: I checked the demo it's working in IE7 and IE8 on my laptop. Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be caused by IE's z-index stacking issue as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070740/879121) to a related question.

On your example I was able to fix the z-index issue by adding a z-index to the `div.wrapper` inside of the table cells.

To get around the layering with cells before and after, you would have to change the z-index of the cells with Javascript.

But since messing with z-index's is getting messy, the best solution would be to put all of the popups outside of and after the table. That will fix your layering issues without crazy/hackish CSS.

Comment: Sadly this would never work in a table grid like a calendar using your method of incrementing the z-index, because you always have a cell before/after/above/below

Comment: @JohnMagnolia I recommend taking the popups outside of the table.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `.hoverContent` is a child of `.wrapper`, you should move it so that it sits on the same level:

```
 <td class="available">
    <div class="wrapper" style="z-index: 0;">
        <span class="date">10</span><strong class="price">£200</strong>
        <a href="/victory_cottage/booking/init/id/1/from/1336611600/nights/7" class="link popme"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="hoverContent">...
```

Set the `td` to be `position:relative`, set `.hoverContent` as `position:absolute` and that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your component itself is positioned absolutely and shown temporarily over other components, just add it to the top level i.e. the page and then you don't have to worry about the table's z-order or type of positioning.